# Mongo Db C# - lookup filter query into collection taking too much time

Tags: c#, mongodb, collections, parallel-processing

Currently I am using below query to filter records in the collection. it seems to be slower with parallel.foreach too , is there some other way to execute it faster?

```
 Parallel.Invoke(

                    () => output = teamCollection.Aggregate().Match(filterTeams).Group(teamProject).ToList(),
                     () => clubs = clubCollection.Find(filter).Project(clubProjection).ToList()
                     );
```

Comment: How large are these collections that you are working with?  Also what are the filter and projection definitions?  I believe that these would play far greater a role in to answering your question.

Comment: This could use a bit more information, there is no way to find the problem with this little information.